# Alamofire 4.0.1 Podspec cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm migrating from 3.1.5 to 4.0.1 I'm using a podspec creating my own library, Using Xcode 8.0 and cocoapods 1.1.1 , but when I update to this version I get this error

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `ExpSwift (from `../`)` required by `Podfile`
- `ExpSwift (from `../`)` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `ExpSwift (from `../`)` dependency were found, but   they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I did updated the deployment target to 10.0 but I get the same error. Do I need to update something else, here us my podspec and podfile

```
s.platform     = :ios, '10.0'
 s.requires_arc = true

 s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
 #s.resource_bundles = {
 #  'ExpSwift' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
 #}

# s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
# s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
s.dependency 'PromiseKit','4.0'
s.dependency 'Alamofire','4.0.0'
s.dependency 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift','8.0.2'
s.dependency 'JSONWebToken','2.0.1'
```

end

And my podfile just reference to my local pod

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ExpSwift_Example' do
 pod "ExpSwift", :path => "../"
end

target 'ExpSwift_Tests' do
 pod "ExpSwift", :path => "../"
end
```

Comment: Alamofire 4.0.0 is working with ios 10.0

Comment: yeah looks like i need tu change the podfile to 10.0